# Auto "expire" all of an authors posts on spcific date

Tags: posts, author

Ok, so here is a slightly weird one that I could not find an answer to... yet.

I've built a classifieds site using WP-Types, but ignore that fact for now.

Is there any way to auto-expire all of an authors' posts all at once on a specific date or after a specific number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not away of any `expired` post status, but you can set the post's status to `draft` of `trash`.

First, you need to set up a cron job to run once in a while, and check if the date has come. Finding the proper time is up to you.

```
// Let's check the scheduled even on WP load
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_post_expiration' );
function schedule_post_expiration() {

    // If the even is not scheduled already, then do schedule it
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'reset-post-status' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( strtotime( '00:00:00' ), 'daily', 'reset-post-status' );
    }

}

// We hook our callback function to our custom action hook to run
// daily and update the post's status
add_action( 'reset-post-status', 'reset_post_status_callback' );
function reset_post_status_callback(){

    // Get the current date
    $date = date( 'Y-m-d' );

    // Set the date we want to check. It should match the above date format.
    $check_date = '2018-02-11';

    // Check if the time has come
    if ( strtotime( $date ) > strtotime( $check_date ) ){

        // Query a list of a specific author's posts
        $author_args = array( 'author' => 123, 'post_status' => 'publish' );

        // Do the query
        $author_query = new WP_Query( $author_args );

        // Check if the query has any post, and setup the post data
        if ( $author_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $author_query->have_posts() {
                $author_query->the_post();

                // Update the post's status
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => get_the_ID(), 'post_status' => 'trash' ) );

            }
        }
        // Reset the posts data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jack-johansson I think this will do that trick.

Think I am going to try and see if this solution can be developed into a plugin or something so that I can simply enter the date on a user's profile.